# Contents not set to ckeditor when deployed on server

Tags: gwt, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in my gwt project. I am setting the html to the ckeditor using the setHTML() method. It works in the development mode but when i deploy the application on the server, the html contents are not set to the ckeditor.
Please help..

Comment: At the very least you should show us your code and explain better what's the problem. What have you tried so far to debug the problem and what are the results.

Comment: `CKConfig config = CKConfig.basic;
CKEditor editor = new CKEditor(config);
VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
panel.add(editor);
String content = "<p>Hi, how are you</p>";
editor.setHTML(content);`

Comment: @AlfonsoML , it is working in the development mode but not when deployed.

Comment: If it works in one server, then check what are the differences with the other server. Check the logs, verify that they have the same set of files, that everything has been uploaded correctly.